# Firestore: Is it equivalent to chain a document with a subcollection calls, and store a document then store its subcollection?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Are `db.document("a").collection("b")` and `some_var = db.document("a"); some_var_2 = some_var.collection("b")` equivalent?

In particular: in both cases, are "a"'s fields retrieved from database and loaded in RAM (especially for the first way)? (in other words: does the first way just retrieve the subcollection without retrieving/loading "a"'s fields?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, you will only generate **document** or **collection references**, so Firestore won't fetch any data until you call a method (such as `.get()`) on it.

So, there is no difference, but you should use the first way in the case you will need to make operations on the entire collection in addition to the single document.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent.

Neither of them actually retrieve any data.  They are just creating references to documents.  You have to call `get()` or attach a listener to actually get the data from the documents.  You should probably familiarize yourself with the [documentation for reading data from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).